# IBM Cloud AppID: How to change password for user in Cloud Directory?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I have an app utilizing IBM Cloud AppID for user management. My users are managed using the Cloud Directory. They can sign up on their own and also request to reset their password.

If I added (test) users without a valid email address, how can I change their passwords? There is no UI for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [AppID management API to change the password](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/app-id/management#changepassword). You can find the AppID APIs in the [security category of all IBM Cloud API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs&category=security).

Either call that API via **curl** or use the [Swagger form](https://eu-gb.appid.cloud.ibm.com/swagger-ui/#/Management%20API%20-%20Cloud%20Directory%20Workflows/mgmt.changePassword). You would need an IAM API key or token, your AppID tenantID, the user's uuid and then provide the new password to set.